# Error thrown from publisher.h header file

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're trying to communicate via publisher/subscriber nodes between a laptop and a PC-104, but whenever we try to send a message, this error is returned:

QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_button_move_to_clicked(int)
[ INFO] [1342642126.367633583]: DOUT clicked. Data: 15.
[ INFO] [1342642126.367836194]: SLOT invoked.
[FATAL] [1342642126.367895559]: ASSERTION FAILED
file = /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/publisher.h
line = 102
cond = false
message =
[FATAL] [1342642126.367953248]: Call to publish() on an invalid Publisher
[FATAL] [1342642126.367994664]:

Trace/breakpoint trap

Which is generated by this line in publisher.h:

```
  if (!impl_)
     {
       ROS_ASSERT_MSG(false, "Call to publish() on an invalid Publisher");
       return;
     }
```

But we're not sure what "!impl_" means, so we can't figure out what exactly is triggering this error. Has anyone dealt with this before?

http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/api/roscpp/html/publisher_8h_source.html
(Full text of publisher.h)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39195/error-thrown-from-publisher.h-header-file/) by [UW NDCL](https://answers.ros.org/users/2777/uw-ndcl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To me it looks like you are trying to call `publish` on an uninitialized publisher object. Make sure that you initialize it by calling NodeHandle::advertise before you are trying to publish anything. Btw., you can check if a publisher is valid by:

```
if( !publisher ) {
  ROS_WARN("Publisher invalid!");
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0